# Sending a POST Request to external API from GCP cloud function returns 500 but not when sent locally

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm currently trying to send a POST request to an external API from a GCP Cloud Function.  I've tested the function extensively locally and it fulfills the request every time and also works from Postman, but when I run the exact same code from within a cloud function, it returns a 500 from the external API every single time.

I'm genuinely at a loss as to why when sending the POST request from within the cloud function it fails every single time.

Does GCP add any headers that might interfere with an external API call or is there a configuration option within the cloud function settings that needs to be configured to allow an external POST request?

I've attempted to implement an http retry mechanism, but that did not work either.

Again, locally and from Postman, the exact same code is successful every time I run it.

Here is the code I use to generate and send the request:

```golang
package email

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/hashicorp/go-retryablehttp"
)

var FailedRequestErr = errors.New("failed request to moosend")

const (
    successCode                  = 0
    moosendHost                  = "api.moosend.com/v3"
    dailyNewsletterMailingListID = "2e461f4c-99d1-4a8e-80ea-168b20bdaf5f"
    mainEmail                    = "jason@functionalbits.io"
    campaignNameBase             = "Functional Bits Newsletter - Issue"
    campaignSubjectBase          = "Functional Bits Issue"
)

type CreatingADraftCampaignRequest struct {
    Name                   string         `json:"Name"`
    Subject                string         `json:"Subject"`
    SenderEmail            string         `json:"SenderEmail"`
    ReplyToEmail           string         `json:"ReplyToEmail"`
    IsAB                   string         `json:"IsAB"`
    ConfirmationToEmail    string         `json:"ConfirmationToEmail,omitempty"`
    WebLocation            string         `json:"WebLocation,omitempty"`
    MailingLists           []MailingLists `json:"MailingLists,omitempty"`
    SegmentID              string         `json:"SegmentID,omitempty"`
    ABCampaignType         string         `json:"ABCampaignType,omitempty"`
    TrackInGoogleAnalytics string         `json:"TrackInGoogleAnalytics,omitempty"`
    DontTrackLinkClicks    string         `json:"DontTrackLinkClicks,omitempty"`
    SubjectB               string         `json:"SubjectB,omitempty"`
    WebLocationB           string         `json:"WebLocationB,omitempty"`
    SenderEmailB           string         `json:"SenderEmailB,omitempty"`
    HoursToTest            string         `json:"HoursToTest,omitempty"`
    ListPercentage         string         `json:"ListPercentage,omitempty"`
    ABWinnerSelectionType  string         `json:"ABWinnerSelectionType,omitempty"`
}

type MailingLists struct {
    MailingListID string  `json:"MailingListId"`
    SegmentID     float64 `json:"SegmentId,omitempty"`
}

type CampaignResponse struct {
    Code    int32       `json:"Code"`
    Err     interface{} `json:"Error"`
    Context interface{} `json:"Context"`
}

type MoosendAPI struct {
    apiKey string
    client *http.Client
}

func NewMoosendAPI(apiKey string) *MoosendAPI {
    retryClient := retryablehttp.NewClient()
    retryClient.RetryMax = 5
    standardClient := retryClient.StandardClient()

    return &MoosendAPI{
        apiKey: apiKey,
        client: standardClient,
    }
}

func (m *MoosendAPI) CreateDraftCampaign(issueNumber string, webLocation string) (*CampaignResponse, error) {
    campaign := CreatingADraftCampaignRequest{
        Name:                   fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", campaignNameBase, issueNumber),
        Subject:                fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", campaignSubjectBase, issueNumber),
        IsAB:                   "false",
        WebLocation:            webLocation,
        MailingLists:           []MailingLists{{MailingListID: dailyNewsletterMailingListID}},
        SenderEmail:            mainEmail,
        ReplyToEmail:           mainEmail,
        ConfirmationToEmail:    mainEmail,
        TrackInGoogleAnalytics: "true",
    }

    body, err := json.Marshal(&campaign)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error marshalling campaign request")
        return nil, err
    }

    fullURL := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s/campaigns/create.json?apikey=%s", moosendHost, m.apiKey)

    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, fullURL, bytes.NewBuffer(body))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("request error")
        return nil, err
    }

    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json")

    log.Printf("request: %+v", req)

    resp, err := m.client.Do(req)
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        return nil, FailedRequestErr
    }
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error sending request")
        return nil, err
    }

    log.Printf("response: %+v", resp)

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    respBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error reading response body")
        return nil, err
    }

    var draftResponse CampaignResponse
    if err := json.Unmarshal(respBody, &draftResponse); err != nil {
        log.Println("error unmarshalling response")
        log.Printf("%+v", draftResponse)
        return nil, err
    }

    return &draftResponse, nil
}

func (m *MoosendAPI) SendCampaign(campaignID string) error {
    fullURL := fmt.Sprintf("https://%s/campaigns/%s/send.json?apikey=%s", moosendHost, campaignID, m.apiKey)

    req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, fullURL, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error creating request")
        return err
    }

    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json")

    resp, err := m.client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error sending request")
        return err
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()
    respBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error reading response body")
        return err
    }

    var sendResponse CampaignResponse
    if err := json.Unmarshal(respBody, &sendResponse); err != nil {
        log.Println("error unmarshalling response")
        log.Printf("%+v", sendResponse)
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Then how it's run in the main function code:

```golang
package function

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/Functional-Bits/emailer-service/internal/email"
    "github.com/Functional-Bits/emailer-service/internal/publish"
)

func CampaignGenerator(ctx context.Context, m publish.PubSubMessage) error {
    moosendAPIKey, ok := os.LookupEnv("MOOSEND_API_KEY")
    if !ok {
        log.Println("missing moosendAPIKey")
    }
    mAPI := email.NewMoosendAPI(moosendAPIKey)

    var msg publish.IncomingMessage
    if err := json.Unmarshal(m.Data, &msg); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return err
    }

    log.Printf("received message: %+v", msg)
    log.Printf("generating draft campaign for issue %s", msg.IssueNumber)

    draftResponse, err := mAPI.CreateDraftCampaign(msg.IssueNumber, msg.FileURL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return err
    }

    log.Printf("draft response: %+v", draftResponse)

    campaignID, ok := draftResponse.Context.(string)
    if !ok {
        log.Printf("response didn't contain an ID: %+v", draftResponse)
        return errors.New("no campaign generated")
    }

    log.Printf("sending campgain %s", campaignID)
    if err := mAPI.SendCampaign(campaignID); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return err
    }

    log.Printf("campaign successfully sent for issue number %s", msg.IssueNumber)
    return nil
}
```

When this code is run locally, It correctly makes the 2 calls and sends an email campaign.  When run from the cloud function I get a 500 internal server error with no additional information as to why. [Link](https://moosendapp.docs.apiary.io/reference/campaigns/creating-managing-campaigns/creating-a-draft-campaign) to API docs.

I get the following response from the external API (from my cloud function logs)

```
response: &{
  Status:500 Internal Server Error 
  StatusCode:500 
  Proto:HTTP/1.1 
  ProtoMajor:1 
  ProtoMinor:1 
  Header:map[Access-Control-Allow-Headers:[Content-Type, Accept, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With] 
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods:[GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT] 
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin:[*] 
  Cache-Control:[private] 
  Content-Length:[12750] 
  Content-Type:[text/html; charset=utf-8] 
  Date:[Sun, 12 Dec 2021 07:00:09 GMT] 
  Server:[Microsoft-IIS/10.0] 
  X-Aspnet-Version:[4.0.30319] 
  X-Powered-By:[ASP.NET] 
  X-Robots-Tag:[noindex, nofollow] 
  X-Server-Id:[1]] 
  Body:0xc0003f04c0 
  ContentLength:12750 
  TransferEncoding:[] 
  Close:false 
  Uncompressed:false 
  Trailer:map[] 
  Request:0xc000160b00 
  TLS:0xc000500630
}
```

The response causes an unmarshal error because no campaign ID is returned.

Comment: It's hard to say without viewing the code that perform the external call. Can you share it? In addition, Cloud Functions runtime environment isn't managed by you. For the request management, especially to receive HTTP request, Google Cloud build a container around your code and add its dependency (requests, flask). Sometime there is dependency confusion. That's why your code, and your dependency versions are important

Comment: An HTTP 5xx error means the external API you are calling crashed. Without details, there are endless possibilities. Even if Cloud Functions added a header, the API should not crash. Edit your question, provide a link to the API and include your code that calls the API.

Comment: Please see the edited original post.

Comment: What do the logs show? Add sufficient logging so that you know which call failed and log the returned message. My guess is there is something wrong with the JSON payload. Review the returned **Error** key. Just to be sure, is the API returning a 500 error?

Comment: @JohnHanley that's the thing, I have plenty of logging and the response from the external API call is just a generic 500 with no additional information.  Like I mentioned, when I run this exact code, same exact body, payload, URL, everything on my local computer or through postman, I get a 200 and the email campaign gets properly generated.

Only when I try to run it via the cloud function does it give me trouble.  I've solicited the company for assistance to see if they can see anything specific in the logs on their side based on my API key, but haven't heard back just yet.

Comment: Edit your question and show the logs that Cloud Functions generate. There are always logs generated. I cannot even determine which part of your code is getting the 500 error. Focus on generating and reading the logs. That will help solve the problem.